# Very Slow PLC Programming and Fault Finding

Tags: c#, .net, plc, opc

I am working in a full production environment that has a range of PLCS around our production mill, each of these PLC's talk back through a 'DataHighway +' network back to a special PC on our LAN Network called the MicroLinks PC. This has the ROCKWELL OPC RSLinx Classic server software on it.

So, recently I have put together a piece of .NET software in c# using the OPC .NET API to read to ROCKWELL OPC server on the Microlinks PC and sync data back into our MYSQL database that is sat on our WINDOWS R2 server PC

Ever since turning on the .net software, the engineers on site have experienced a massive slow down in developing new PLC scripts and fault finding.

Some of the reports are even as bad as 10 second lags.

Consequently, we have had to turn of the .NET software to sync the data to allow the Engineers to do their work swiftly without issues.

So i am looking for some advice on where or what i should look for, any resources to read for this type of problem etc. As PLC and networks are way out of my depth, I am just the .NET programmer.

Here is the structure of our network:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which type of rockwell PLCs you are using. I'm most familiar with the ControlLogix platform so I'll talk about that.

1. The ethernet card in a controllogix PLC connects at 100Mb/s but the card can't actually handle 100Mb/s continuously. A 1756-ENBt card can handle about 5000 packets per second, the EN2T roughly double that. There are formulas in the rockwell docs explain how to calculate packets per second but another option when you have a running system is to connect the 'Logix5000 task monitor' that comes with RS Logix and verify the CPU usage **of the Ethernet card** I think Rockwell recommends you keep it under 60%. If you are requesting too many packets then this CPU won't keep up
2. The PLC itself can starve communications. Controllogix has a "overhead time slice" setting which is the percent of time the PLC spends servicing communication tasks as opposed to running its own logic. Increasing this percentage can improve comms a bit.

It sounds like your program is putting a large burden on the PLC. Does it get better if you slow down your app so that it is not pulling as much data as fast?

One easy way to reduce the number of packets required to retrieve a block of data without slowing down the update rate is to put it all in one array. RSLinx will then be able to optimize the request instead of pulling individual tags

Answer (score 2):

I have had plenty of troubles using Rockwell RSLinx on my local PC trying to find the IP address of a PLC plugged directly into my ethernet port.  Using the "Autobrowse" option, it completely locks up my PC trying to scan the ports and IP addresses for targets.

It might just be poorly optimized Rockwell software causing issues.  You also may be exchanging a whole lot of data and your server PC is struggling to keep up.

I would contact Rockwell/Allen Bradley support for help with this.  They will probably want some cash to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost deinifitely over-polling the PLC.  Try polling less and less frequently until find a value that doesn't slow down the network  For example, if you're requesting data every 100ms now, change that once per second.  Then once per minute.  Then once every 15 minutes.  At each step check the comms speed for the programming terminals.